# How to get the content of an uploaded file in a Meteor app?

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor

I don't want to store the binary file, I just need to load its Base-64 value onto the page.

With PHP, I can just have a server script echoing back the Base-64 value of a posted file. But the workflow in Meteor really eludes me.

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Actually for my case, I may just use fileReader.readAsDataURL. I'll report my finding on browser compatibility later.

Comment: these two might help, https://gist.github.com/3922137 https://gist.github.com/4413727

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer. I just went with filepicker.io

The FileReader API is actually quite limited in terms of browser compatibility. (http://caniuse.com/filereader)

The free plan of filepicker.io currently allows 5000 file uploads per month which is fine for my case.